How to get metadata like username and subscriber count from Snapchat login in Flutter?
I'm integrating Snapchat login into my Flutter app using the provided Login Kit. However, I'm unsure about how to retrieve additional metadata such as the user's username and the number of subscribers they have. The Login Kit seems to provide limited information, including the display name, Bitmoji, and an external ID that appears to be primarily for app-specific onboarding of users.
Is there an API or SDK available that allows access to more detailed metadata, such as the username and subscriber count, when integrating Snapchat login into a Flutter app? Alternatively, are there any workarounds or strategies to obtain this information through the existing Snapchat SDK?
Any insights or suggestions would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!
